# How to read files from HDFS using Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I have built a recommendation system using Apache Spark with datasets stored locally in my project folder, now i need to access these files from HDFS.

How can i read files from HDFS using Spark ?

This is how i initialize my Spark session:

```
SparkContext context = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-ml").setMaster("local")
                .set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310").set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:54310"));
        Configuration conf = context.hadoopConfiguration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem");
        this.session = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(context).getOrCreate();
        System.out.println(conf.getRaw("fs.default.name"));
        System.out.println(context.getConf().get("fs.defaultFS"));
```

All the outputs return `hdfs://localhost:54310` which is the correct uri for my HDFS.

When trying to read a file from HDFS:

```
session.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("hdfs://localhost:54310/recommendation_system/movies/ratings.csv").cache();
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:54310/recommendation_system/movies/ratings.csv, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:930)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:2034)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:253)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:253)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.collect$(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.dastamn.sparkml.analytics.SparkManager.<init>(SparkManager.java:36)
    at com.dastamn.sparkml.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

What can i do to solve this issue ?

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I’m using Spark 2.4.2 and Hadoop 3.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the configuration that solved the problem:

```
SparkContext context = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-ml").setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310").set("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:54310")
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName())
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.server", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.class.getName())
                .set("spark.hadoop.conf", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.class.getName()));
        this.session = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(context).getOrCreate();
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things from the code snippet pasted:
1. When a hadoop property has to be set as part of using `SparkConf`, it has to be prefixed with `spark.hadoop.`, in this case key `fs.default.name` needs to be set as `spark.hadoop.fs.default.name` and likewise for the other properties.
2. The argument to the `csv` function does not have to tell about the HDFS endpoint, Spark will figure it out from default properties, since it is already set.

> session.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema",
>   true).csv("/recommendation_system/movies/ratings.csv").cache();

If the default filesystem properties are not set part of HadoopConfiguration, the complete URI isrequired for Spark/Hadoop to figure out the filesystem to use.
(Also the object name `conf` is not used)
3. In the above case, looks like Hadoop not was able to find a FileSystem for `hdfs://` URI prefix and resorted to use the default filesystem which is `local` in this case(since it is using `RawLocalFileSystem`to process the path).
Make sure that `hadoop-hdfs.jar` is present in class path which has `DistributedFileSystem`,to instatntiate the FS objects for HDFS.